# Nodejs Async skipping await

Tags: node.js, async-await

So I'm missing something here. My goal here is to have each of the `console.log` statements in sequential order, but some reason the runtime is continuing without waiting for my `await` command.
Here's a simplified example:

```js
# Setup a method
exports.selectAll = async (db) => {
  db.run("SELECT * FROM stats", (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else {
      console.log("Hit1");
      return data;
    }
  });
};
```

Just a simple process for returning some longer command from the db. However when I go to call this:

```js
## Runtime
(async () => {
  const db = await exports.open();
  const data = await exports.selectAll(db);
  console.log("Hit2");
  console.log(data);
  console.log("Hit3");
  exports.close(db);
})()
```

I get the following output:

```sh
Hit2
undefined
Hit3
sql - connected
Hit1
sql - db closed
```

Why is the function not waiting for `const data = await exports.selectAll(db);`?

Quick aside:
I've confirmed its not and issue with db.run, as if I `console.log` right after the Hit1 I can see the return of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because inside `selectAll` you aren't returning anything awaitable, and since the `db.run` call is IO bound, it'll fire the query and hand context back to the thread, meaning the console logs will be processed first (before the DB callback runs).

If the library you are using doesn't support Promises then you'll need to create your own:

```
exports.selectAll = db => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db.run("SELECT * FROM stats", (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data));
});
```

Comment: Interesting, for some reason I thought because `exports.selectAll` was tagged as `async` it would return a promise by default resolving when the function returned, and didn't need to declare the promise within it. That appears to have resolved my ordering issue.

Comment: @Gates it does, however, it doesn't magically make the code you have _inside_ that function async (you are using a callback mechanism and therefore need to control when that Promise is resolved)